# Shopify script tag: 302 CORB error, script tag redirects to authentication flow

Tags: heroku, shopify-app, http-status-code-302, shopify-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am stuck. I am using node.js with a custom Shopify app built using Shopify cli.

The script tag I created using graphql keeps throwing a CORB error when it goes live.

```
createScripts({
                  variables: {
                    input: {
                      src: "https://arcane-spire-11260.herokuapp.com/thanks-script.js",
                      displayScope: "ORDER_STATUS"
                    },
                  },
```

It seems like I have to authenticate first then it shows but I want it to always show the script tag.

Why does my Heroku server always need to authenticate with the shop before it can display the script?

- Add script tag
- Throws CORB error
- Click on the script tag src link (https://arcane-spire-11260.herokuapp.com/thanks-script.js?shop=littosnz.myshopify.com)
- Redirects me to authenticate the store
- Script then works

I just want it to be public to everyone all the time. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am stuck with it as well.